# Why would a type int variable be used in a string input in C?

Tags: c, io, stream, stdin, type-conversion

I am working through methods of input and output in C, and I have been presented with a segment of code that has an element that I cannot understand. The purport of this code is to show how the 'echoing' and 'buffered' input/outputs work, and in the code, they have a type 'int' declared for, as I understand, characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int ch;    //This is what I do not get: why is this type 'int'?

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
        putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not on firm footing with type casting as it is, and this 'int' / 'char' discrepancy is undermining all notions that I have regarding data types and compatibility.

Comment: I would like to entertain the possibility of a typo from the author. I just don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getc`, `fgetc` and `getchar` functions return int because they are capable of handling binary data, as well as providing an in-band signal of an error or end-of-data condition.

Except on certain embedded platforms which have an unusual byte size, the type `int` is capable of representing all of the byte values from `0` to `UCHAR_MAX` as positive values. In addition, it can represent negative values, such as the value of the constant `EOF`.

The type `unsigned char` would only be capable of representing the values `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`, and so the functions would not be able to use the return value as a way of indicating the inability to read another byte of data. The value `EOF` is convenient because it can be treated as if it were an input symbol; for instance it can be included in a `switch` statement which handles various characters.

There is a little bit more to this because in the design of C, values of `short` and `char` type (signed or unsigned) undergo *promotion* when they are evaluated in expressions.

In classic C, before prototypes were introduced, when you pass a `char` to a function, it's actually an `int` value which is passed. Concretely:

```
int func(c)
char c;
{
   /* ... */
}
```

This kind of old style definition does not introduce information about the parameter types.
When we call this as `func(c)`, where `c` has type `char`, the expression `c` is subject to the usual promotion, and becomes a value of type `int`.  This is exactly the type which is expected by the above function definition. A parameter of type `char` actually passes through as a value of type `int`. If we write an ISO C prototype declaration for the above function, it has to be, guess what:

```
int func(int); /* not int func(char) */
```

Another legacy is that character constants like `'A'` actually have type `int` and not `char`. It is noteworthy that this changes in C++, because C++ has overloaded functions. Given the overloads:

```
void f(int);
void f(char);
```

we want `f(3)` to call the former, and `f('A')` to call the latter.

So the point is that the designers of C basically regarded `char` as being oriented toward representing a compact *storage location*, and the smallest addressable unit of memory.  But as far as data manipulation in the processor was concerned, they were thinking of the values as being word-sized `int` values: that character processing is essentially data manipulation based on `int`.

This is one of the low-level facets of C. *In machine languages on byte-addressable machines, we usually think of bytes as being units of storage, and when we load the into registers to work with them, they occupy a full register, and so become 32 bit values (or what have you). This is mirrored in the concept of promotion in C.*

Comment: My thought process: "You un-accepted my answer? ... And you didn't accept @jxh's answer?! ... oh, right this is much better. Carry on." +1.

Answer (score 4):

`getchar()` returns an `int` type because it is designed to be able to return a value that cannot be represented by `char` to indicate `EOF`. (C.11 §7.21.1 ¶3 and §7.21.7.6 ¶3)

Your looping code should take into account that `getchar()` might return `EOF`:

```
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (ch != '\n') putchar(ch);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about the EOF thing. +1.

Comment: EOF can be represented by `signed char`, and by `char` if char happens to be signed. It cannot be represented by `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Kaz: Except a `signed char` with `-1` is not `int` (and `EOF` is `int`), and a `signed char` with `-1` may be a valid value for a character encoding.

Comment: That doesn't matter; the value of the `EOF` constant can go into `signed char`.  `signed char` values are promoted. When you assign one signed char to another, the value becomes `int` in transit. The problem is that a value -1 of `signed char` is also a valid byte. So you cannot read binary streams reliably if one of the byte values is ambiguous with `EOF`.

Comment: @Kaz: I don't think we are in disagreement. Exactly what is your nitpick?

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `getchar()` is `int`. It returns the ASCII code of the character it's just read. This is (and I know someone's gonna correct me on this) the same as the `char` representation, so you can freely compare them and so on.

Why is it this way? The `getchar()` function is ancient -- from the very earliest days of K&R C. `putchar()` similarly takes an `int` argument, when you'd think it might take a `char`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow. Both of my C texts make no mention of that whatsoever.  Thanks!